# @Id annotation Causing duplication in list

Tags: spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am using Hibernate for calling Stored procedure

```
Response returned by Stored procedure 


         receiverId  fcmId    source
           1234        xyz     android
           45678       abc     web
           9876        fgh     android
           1234       ygh     ios
```

Hibernet @EntityClass

```
 @Entity
 public class receieverDetails {

@Id
@Column(name="receiverId")
private String receiverUserId;

@Column(name="fcmId")
private String fcmIds;

private String source;

 }
```

I am getting List of receiverDetails from database

if List contain duplicate receiverId as show is above response, 1st one is replacing the 4th details

Code for Binding

```
     ProcedureCall procedureCall1 = 
                       session.createStoredProcedureCall(Strings.StoredProcedureNames.GET_RECEIVER_INFO_OF_SPONSORED_MESSAGE,receieverDetails.class);

   Output output1 = procedureCall1.getOutputs().getCurrent();
                if(output1.isResultSet()) {
    List<receieverDetails> receievers = ((ResultSetOutput) output1).getResultList();
 }
```

i think this is causing by @Id annotation in the entity class, Because it is happening with same receiverIds only

Kindly Help me on this

Comment: r u add row in db directly? is receiverId is PK? r u add constraint for ur receiverId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code by providing the `@Id` annotation to the column `receiverId`, you are telling the code that this field is to be used as the primary key for the table.So, when fetching the data the issue occurs as there are duplicate values in the table for this column. Either you need to set the primary key correctly, or make this column as primary key in table and correct your code.
If you are using the same entity class to persist data and make column  `receiverId` primary key then try using the below :

```
@Entity
public class receieverDetails {

@Id
@Column(name="receiverId",unique=true,nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String receiverUserId;

@Column(name="fcmId")
private String fcmIds;

private String source;

}
```

`unique=true` in `@Column` is a shortcut for `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"receiverId"}` and other particular constraints.The `@GeneratedValue` annotation is to configure the way of increment of the specified column(field).

or if the primary key of the table is some other field in table please correct the code to reflect the same.